# iOS app crashes with 'All Exceptions' enabled

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

iOS app crashes with 'All Exceptions' enabled, but with it disabled, the app runs fine and never crashes.

I get this in the console.

(lldb)

and shows thread breakpoint 1.1 at UIApplication.

Gives me not much else, not sure how to trace it.

Comment: what is the crash log? are you sure it is a crash, for example avaudioplayer stops execution when all exceptions are enabled but pressing continue a couple of time makes it continue and to prevent that behavior you have to enable only breakpoints in Obj-C exceptions (not C++ exceptions).

Comment: @guenis, +1, and to further elaborate-- just because an exception is raised, it doesn't necessarily mean that it's a bad thing or issue within the app... there are many frameworks that actually throw (and usually catch) exceptions for performance reasons... such as Core Data for another example.

Comment: That's not a crash, it's a _breakpoint_, like the message says.